# javascript return multiple strings with .join() --- string[i].join("") not working

Tags: javascript

creating a solution to a piglatin homework problem. successfully returning single words.  going for multiple words now.

everything is working up until outputting two separate words. attempting to use join to output multiple words, but not working

attempted to output with this: // return `${splitWords[i].join("")}yay`;

hit a wall after looking through MDN and stackoverflow.

```
function pigLatin(string) {
  // Global variables
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const splitWord = string
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .split("");
  const words = string.split(" ");

  // Multiple Words iteration
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const splitWords = words[i]
      .toLowerCase()
      .trim()
      .split("");
    console.log(splitWords);
    for (let i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
      for (let v = 0; v < vowels.length; v++) {
        if (splitWords[i][0] === vowels[v]) {
          // return `${splitWords[i].join("")}yay`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

expected results are to return multiple joined words with "yay" attached at end.

actual result is splitWords[i].join("") is not a function.

Comment: You are using `v < vowels.length`, but where does `vowels` come from?

Comment: Each element of `splitWords` is going to be a *string*, not an array, and there's no `.join()` available for strings.

Comment: Could you please provide an example input-output? Your issue is not that clear.

Comment: Is the goal to output a string of words that start with vowels with a yay at the end of it?

Comment: @justDan vowels is a global variable above the given snippet.

Comment: @Pointy console.log(splitWords[i]); prints: 
[ 'a', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' ]
a
o
[ 'a', 'w', 'a', 'k', 'e' ]
a
a
e
aword awakeyay

Comment: When you `.split()` a string, you get an array of strings. In your case each string will contain a single character.

Comment: @Pointy agree. how would i independently join array[0] and array[1] and print each new joined word with + 'yay' at the end?

Comment: I would accumulate a string, starting with `""`, and add new matching characters (vowels) with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,the problem here is that you are creating an array of `string`s and accesing one of their elements as if it was the array.In this expression `splitWords[i].join("")`.Try this instead `return ${splitWords}yay`.

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking like a C-Programmer. You are writing JavaScript now, so stop doing that. Thinking the wrong way I mean. Also you should spend a little bit more effort in the naming of things. Names are important! It's well worth watching [Giving code a good name - Kevlin Henney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzJ94TMPcD8) if you have a spare hour and a half.

Anyway back to the main point. Javascript shines in functional programming. It's pretty much built on the concept of functions being first class citizens. That's why the Array has all these fancy methods like `find`, `map` and `grep` and so on.

So you should get into the habit of playing with the language. Consider this code:

```
function pigLatin(input) {

  const maybe_add_yay = function(word) {
    const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    const yay_re = new RegExp( vowels.join("|") );
    return yay_re.test(word) ? word + 'yay' : word;
  };

  return input
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .split(" ") 
    .map( maybe_add_yay )
    .join(" ");
}

console.log( pigLatin("bababa Güllühüllü kptnk giumalo") );
// bababayay Güllühüllü kptnk giumaloyay
```

This nicely decouples two problems (parsing input into chunks and process the chunk). The "collect multiple values and join them" problem is autosolved by the use of the `Array`methods.

I wasn't sure which piglatin rules you actually wanted to implement, so this code just adds yay to whatever word contains one of the vowels, as your OP seems to indicate.

If you need another rule you can just tweak the `maybe_add_yay` function. Like getting rid of the vowels array completely and use a handwritten (arbitrarily complex) regular expression in the first place.

Comment: its generally best to help the OP with their question without dramatically changing their code, otherwise they won't understand what they did wrong in the first place.

Comment: But using C-style for IS what they did wrong in the first place. If a student tries to spalt wood with a hammer, you don't correct their grip to the hammer, you tell them to use an axe.

Comment: JavaScript is a multi-paradigm language. It has both `for` loops and `.forEach()`, you can write imperatively or you can use higher-order functions. You're imposing your opinion of the best style, implying that there's something wrong with other styles.

Comment: This type of opinionated answer might be appropriate on [codereview.se], but I agree with @ChrisSandvik that it doesn't really answer the question by doing a complete redesign.

Comment: You're right, I am opinionated. Like a good teacher should. I gave good advice stemming from 20 years in programming. The OP is free to take it or leave it.

Comment: This isn't an advice forum, he didn't ask for best practice suggestions. I'll often add suggestions of better ways to solve a problem *after* answering the question.

Comment: Then by all means, go ahead and post the "correct" answer if you're so concerned.